# Change select option on scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using Waypoints (github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) to change the selected nav option as you scroll down the page. However I am switching to a select dropdown on mobile for the nav. I'm wondering if it's possible to add this functionality using waypoints and change the selected option my my select as I scroll past these sections.

Here is the function changing my nav on desktop

```
function getRelatedNavigation(el){
  return $('.desktopnav ul li a[href=#'+$(el).attr('id')+']');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is check all the elements y position in the document and return the one that is just passed?

```
function getRelatedNavigation() {
    var elements = $('.anchor');
    var currentScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    elements.each(function(index,value) {
        if (currentScroll > $(value).position.y) return $(value);
    });
});
$('.desktopnav ul li a[href="#'+getRelatedNavigation().attr('id')+'"]').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
$('#mobileselect').children().removeAttr('selected');
$('#mobileselect').children('[value="'+getRelatedNavigation().attr('id')+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

I dont know what labeling you are using for your waypoints, or anchors. In the example above I would mark them as class='anchor'

so

```
// Navigation
<ul class='desktopnav'>
    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#other">other</a></li>
</ul>

//// Ways down
<div id='something' class='anchor'>some content</div>
<div id='other' class='anchor'>other content</div>
```

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. This function is working well. What I am wondering is if I can adapt this to change a select as I scroll at the same time. <select id='mobileselect'/>            perhaps adding something like this to the function:   return $('select[name^="mobileselect"] option[value=(el)]').attr('selected','selected');

Comment: @SethTipton `$('#mobileselect').children().removeAttr("selected");` then you would select the option based on the id `$('#mobileselect').children('[value='+getRelatedNavigation().attr('id')+']).attr("selected","selected");` This is assuming the value of the <option> element is === to the id of the anchors

Comment: `return $('#cn17select').children('[value='+getRelatedNavigation().attr('id')+']').prop('selected', true);`          and           `return $('#cn17select').children('[value='+getRelatedNavigation().attr('id')+']').attr('selected','selected');`            both validate but it's still not working :(

Comment: @SethTipton Log `$('#cn17select').children('option[value="'+getRelatedNavigation().attr('id')+'"]')` to the console to make sure it it selecting the right option element. Also you may need to remove the selected attribute from the other `<option>` elements. And make sure that the `<option value="{{ same as id }}">Title</option>`